# Apache: Allow directory browsing when using SVNParentPath?

Tags: apache-2.2, svn, httpd, mod-dav-svn

I have the following setup:

```
<Location /repos>
  DAV svn
  SVNParentPath /home/svn/repos
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "SVN"
  AuthUserFile /home/svn/.htpasswd
  Order deny,allow
  Require valid-user
</Location>
```

Users can access their svn repositories like this:

```
http://theserver/repos/therepository
```

If you try to access the following address in the browser...

```
http://theserver/repos
```

You get a 403 Forbidden. I'd like to make it so that users can browse that folder and see the repositories.

I thought adding the following

```
<Directory /home/svn/repos>
  Options +FollowSymlinks +Indexes
  AllowOverride all
</Directory>
```

Would do it, but I still get 403 Forbidden...

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `SVNListParentPath` to `On` and try again.

Comment: That sounds like exactly what I need. I will try that. Thanks!